# How to search for a record correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to Rails & ActiveRecord and am working on my first CLI app. I want to allow a user to be able to retrieve information based on their target input. For example, if they want a list of happy people, they should get a list of ALL happy people.

I have come up with this code, it works but not really.

`types_list = People.where(types: input).map {|ppl| ppl.person_name}`

Some of the information is is stored like this:

```
id  | person_name  | types
----------------------------------
01  | James Lee    | happy
02  | Sandra Lee   | sad
03  | Daniel Seong | happy, sad
04  | Cody Kim     | happy
05  | etc...       |
```

The above code only returns "James Lee, Cody Kim". However, I also want it to include "Daniel Seong". Basically all `person_name:` where the `types:` includes happy.

Comment: Is `types` an array field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the string instead, if `types` is a `string` or `text` field, try this

```
types_list = People.where("types LIKE ?", "%#{input}%").map {|ppl| ppl.person_name}
```

It will return every record with `types` `hello`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

@rajdeep-singh is totally right!

Additionally you could add a scope to the Person model:

```
# app/models/person.rb
scope :happy, -> { where("types LIKE ?", "%happy%") }
```

Usage:

```
Person.happy.pluck(:person_name)
```